# Inspect Devices is not shown in Chrome

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, web-inspector

I was using `Inspect Devices` option `(Chrome menu > More tools > Inspect Devices)` in Google Chrome for remotely debugging my `Cordova` based Android applications. But this option has suddenly disappeared from the Chrome menu. Has the option been moved to some other place ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply  run this `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome or install [ADB plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage) to your chrome (which opens the same inspection page)

Answer (score 1):

Try entering `chrome://inspect` in the address bar

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I can see this does answer the question, as its how I and many others inspect devices on Chrome. If you could be more specific with your issue with the answer I'll be happy to expand or clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about 'has it been moved to some other place', it appears that it is being moved to dev tools and will not be accessible where it has previously been.

See this Chromium code review for details: https://codereview.chromium.org/1182493009

Additional information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/4ElNcRavLjE